# Display array results from an API inside of a table, based on stored database values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Not sure how to exactly ask this question so let me try to explain.

I'm trying to display dividend amount data for each stock (stock symbol stored in db) inside of a table. This dividend data is coming from the `IEX API` and while I can echo out the results normally and just get them in a list, like this:

```
FB : 0
GOOGL : 0
AAPL : 2.52
```

I don't know how to display them inside of a table row, for each of those stocks. I just get `AAPL : 2.52` for all rows. So it essentially seems like at some point the code doesn't know what data to get for what stock and just prints `AAP`L for all three.

This is relevant piece of the code:

```
<?php
    // Initialising variables to store extracted information
    $name = [];
    $symbol = [];
    $open = [];
    $close = [];
    $high = [];
    $low = [];
    $lastprice = [];
    $y = 0;
    $z = '';
    $key = "93dcc722279c3a7577f248b09ef6167f";

$memberid = $_SESSION['memberID'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE memberID = $memberid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Check if databse is empty
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $sym[$y] = $row["stocks_symbol"];
        $pri[$y] = $row["price"];
        $vol[$y] = $row["quantity"];
        $id[$y] = $row["memberid"];
        $y += 1;
    }
}
// If database empty
else 
{
    ?><h1><center><?php
    echo "Portfolio Empty";
    ?></h1></center><?php
    die();
}
mysqli_close($conn);

// Adding all stock names in one variable to enable API call
for($a=0;$a<$y;$a++)
{
    $z = $z.$sym[$a].',';
}

$z = rtrim($z,",");


// API call
$contents = file_get_contents("http://marketdata.websol.barchart.com/getQuote.json?key=$key&symbols=$z&mode=R");
$contents = json_decode($contents, true);

$div = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=$z&types=stats&filter=dividendRate");  
$div = json_decode($div,TRUE);  
foreach($div as $divi => $value) {
echo '<br/>'. $divi.' : '. $value['stats']['dividendRate'];
}

// Check successfull API call
if($contents["status"]["code"] == 200) 
{
    foreach($contents['results'] as $result) 
    {
        array_push($name,$result['name']);
        array_push($symbol,$result['symbol']);
        array_push($open,$result['open']);
        array_push($close,$result['close']);
        array_push($high,$result['high']);
        array_push($low,$result['low']);
        array_push($lastprice,$result['lastPrice']);
    }

}        
// If API call unsuccessful
else 
{
    ?>
    <h1><center>"Error retreiving data. Please try again later."</center></h1>
    <?php
    die();
}
?>
<!-- Generating Output in tabular format -->
<table class='table table-responsive'>
    <tr class='head warning'>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Symbol</td>
        <td>Open</td>
        <td>Close</td>
        <td>High</td>
        <td>Low</td>
        <td>Last Price</td>
        <td>Price Bought</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Change Per Stock</td>
        <td>Profit/Loss</td>
        <td>Advanced Data</td>
        <td>Dividend</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        for($x=0;$x<$y;$x++) 
        {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $name[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $symbol[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $open[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $close[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $high[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $low[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $lastprice[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pri[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vol[$x]; ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                    if($pri[$x] > $lastprice[$x]) 
                    {?>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down">
                        <?php echo $lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x];
                    }
                    else if($pri[$x] < $lastprice[$x]) 
                    {?>
                        </i>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up">
                        <?php echo $lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x];
                        ?></i><?php
                    }
                    else
                        echo '0';
                    ?></td>

                <td><?php 
                    if($pri[$x] > $lastprice[$x])
                    {?>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down">
                        <?php echo ($lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x]) * $vol[$x];
                    }
                    else if($pri[$x] < $lastprice[$x]) 
                    {?>
                        </i>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up">
                        <?php echo ($lastprice[$x]-$pri[$x]) * $vol[$x];
                        ?></i><?php
                    }
                    else
                        echo '0'; ?>
                </td>
                <td><center><button id="opener1" class='btn btn-success' >Click to view advanced data</button></center>
                    <div id="dialog1" title="Advanced Company Data">Company Description:<br></div>
                    <script>
                    $("#dialog1").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false
                             });
                        $("#opener1").click(function() {
                        $("#dialog1").dialog("open", "modal", true );
                             });
                    </script>
                </td>

                <td>
                     <?php echo '<br/>'. $divi.' : '. $value['stats']['dividendRate']; ?>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</table>
```

In short, I'm asking about the last `td` in the table and how to change it so that it displays the dividend amount for the correct symbol in the row, not `AAPL` for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$divi` and `$value` in the last `<td />`. Those are variables from the `foreach` at the top (`foreach($div as $divi => $value)`) and their values are set from the last iteration of that foreach loop.

In your last `<td />`, you should be using values relevant to the loop you're in, `for($x=0;$x<$y;$x++)`. It looks like you want `$symbol[$x]` and `$div[$symbol[$x]]`.

Your code needs a lot of work, though. Keep practicing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this, how am I supposed to implement it? Do I put the actual loop inside of that row? Sorry but a bit lost here... It's not that I'm necessarily looking for an exact answer but even some guidelines/tutorials would be great. Thanks for your help though, appreciate it!

Comment: Replace `<?php echo '<br/>'. $divi.' : '. $value['stats']['dividendRate']; ?>` with `<?php echo '<br/>'. $symbol[$x].' : '. $div[$symbol[$x]]; ?>`

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I tried it just now and it works but not fully yet. While I do get the correct symbols for each row, it says 'Array' instead of the actual number and displays this: "Notice: Array to string conversion". Any idea how to solve that? I need to reference it slightly differently, right? Thanks again!